# Create List of Access Denied Files & Folders

Tags: windows, permissions, icacls

I want to make a list of access denied files/folders for a given account.  I'm aware "icacls" handles making lists of files/folders given an account name.

e.g.  This command lists access denied per folder on screen:

```
icacls c:\*. /findsid "User" /T /C /L /Q > c:\results.txt
```

...but it doesn't list the access denied folders in the  results file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I figured it out.  The issue was that there's two ways to output:

1. Through "STDOUT"
2. Through "STDERR"

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/110930#/en-us/kb/110930

So, I can just execute something like so:

> icacls c:*. /findsid "User" /T /C /L /Q 2> c:\resultsFolders.txt
>
> icacls c:*.* /findsid "User" /T /C /L /Q 2> c:\resultsFiles.txt

Comment: Wouldn't that be `icacls c:*.* /findsid "User" /T /C /L /Q > c:\updatedFiles.txt 2> c:\accessDeniedFiles.txt`..? Another thought is that using `c:*.` and `c:*.*` is not 100% accurate. You will get better (ie: more accurate) results if you use a `for (dir /AD)` statement..

Comment: How's using wildcards any different?

Comment: Just that `*.` can pick up files and folders without an extension, just like `*.*` can pick up both files and folders with an extension.

Comment: Using `dir /ad` will only list directories and `dir /a-d` will only list files. Using them in a 'for' loop would look like this: `for /f %G in ('"dir /ad /b"') do @echo %G`.. (When using the for loop inside a batch file, be sure to use `%%G` instead of `%G`.)